# Laravel on Railway: file_put_contents Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

Im deploying my laravel app on railway and having an error, someone know hot to fix it ? thanks

First error: tring execute Artisan::call('view:clear');

```
ErrorException
file_put_contents(/app/bootstrap/cache/config.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Second error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES')
```

Comment: For first error: You'll need to give permission in bootstrap folder to 775
if still error then run this command ( php artisan config:cache )

If above working fine then it might help resolve second issue as it requires a fresh cache to load.

Comment: im sorry how can I do it? thanks (im using railway)